# Nest can't cope with a big database model with EF6/MVC5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, elasticsearch, asp.net-mvc-5, nest

I've been given a database against which basic CRUD operations should be possible. This was quickly accomplished by using .NET 4.5/MVC5 and EF6. This means Database First approach.

New requirement: (Elastic)Search.

When creating an index for a custom class (not linked to others in the model), everything is fine. When I use a class with a lot of foreign keys, things stop working. The database consists off 100 tables, with 400+ foreign keys.

I think the problem might be circular references (Customer has n Contracts, which has a reference to the customer, which has a list of Contracts, ... You get the picture). Eventually I get an OutOfMemory Exception and everything comes crashing down.

Code:

```
public static Uri node;
public static ConnectionSettings settings;
public static ElasticClient client;

public ActionResult TestIndex()
    {
        node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "crudapp");
        client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
        indexSettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
        indexSettings.NumberOfShards = 1;

        //The next line causes the OutOfMemoryException
        client.CreateIndex(c => c.Index("crudapp")
                                 .InitializeUsing(indexSettings)
                                 .AddMapping<Customer>(map => map.MapFromAttributes(maxRecursion: 1)));


        foreach (Customer c in db.Customer.Where(a => a.Active == true))
            client.Index(c);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

How can I tell Nest to stop recursing or to not use certain objects?

Sample classes:

```
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.CustomerContract = new HashSet<CustomerContract>();
        }

        public int Customerid { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CustomerContract> CustomerContract { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CustomerContract
    {
        public CustomerContract()
        {
            this.Host = new HashSet<Host>();
        }

        public int CustomerContractid { get; set; }
        public string CustomerContractName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Host> Host { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OutOfMemoryException` is almost certainly coming from the JSON serialization of your `Customer` object. As such, the issue isn't one of NEST or Elasticsearch functionality, but of JSON.NET functionality.

You could handle this in one of two ways:

**1. Serialize the large object selectively**

[This article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size) by the author of JSON.NET discusses reducing the size of objects. You might furnish properties with the [JsonIgnoreAttribute property](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) to instruct the serializer to ignore certain properties. Or an implementation of [IContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) may be less intrusive on the definitions of your EF objects (especially given that they're database-first generated), but I'm not sure whether this can be used in conjunction with the NEST dependency on JSON.NET.

If you're out of options for dealing with NEST's dependency on JSON.NET, you could always find another way to serialize your object and "go raw" by using the Elasticsearch.NET syntax instead of NEST (which essentially builds on-top of Elasticsearch.NET). So instead of a call to `ElasticClient.Index(..)`, make a call to `ElasticClient.Raw.Index(..)`, where the `body` parameter is a JSON string representation (of your own construction) of the object you wish to index.

**2. Project the large object to a smaller data transfer object**

Instead of indexing a `Customer` object, map only the properties you want to index into a data transfer object (DTO) that targets your Elasticsearch schema / document type.

```
foreach (Customer c in db.Customer.Where(a => a.Active == true))
    client.Index(new MyElasticsearchTypes.Customer()
        {
            CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
            CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
            Description = c.Description
        });
```

In C#, you've got a lot of options for how to handle creation of such a DTO, including:

1. Explicitly typed objects with manual mapping (like my example).
2. Explicitly typed objects with a mapping tool like [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/).
3. Dynamic objects.

**Flat by design**

Be aware that using Elasticsearch isn't a case of simply throwing your data into "the index". You need to start thinking in terms of "documents", and come to terms with what that means when you're trying to index data that has come from a relational database. The Elasticsearch guide article [Data In, Data Out](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/data-in-data-out.html) is a good place to start reading. Another article called [Managing relations inside Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/) is particularly relevant to your situation:

> At it's heart, Elasticsearch is a flat hierarchy and trying to force relational data into it can be very challenging. Sometimes the best solution is to judiciously choose which data to denormalize, and where a second query to retrieve children is acceptable